# "Cleanup called..." Message log Tensorflow.js (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, mnist

I am using around 60000 + 10000 Images for creating the training and validation dataset using a generator
( Images used are the MNIST Images of Handwritten Digits in the PNG Format ).
But when I fit the model using them, "Cleanup called" message logs are constantly getting printed.

```
  function* dataGenerator(type) {

    const dataRoot = `MNIST/${type}-Data`;
    const labels = fs.readdirSync(dataRoot);

    for (let _idx = 0; _idx < labels.length; _idx++) {
      const label = labels[_idx];
      const files = fs.readdirSync(`${dataRoot}/${label}`);

      for (let idx = 0; idx < files.length; idx++) {
        const img = fs.readFileSync(`${dataRoot}/${label}/${files[idx]}`);
        const imageTensor = tf.node.decodePng(img, 1);
        const oneHotArr = new Array(labels.length).fill(0);
        oneHotArr[label] = 1;
        const oneHotTensor = tf.tensor1d(oneHotArr);
        yield { xs: imageTensor, ys: oneHotTensor };
      };
    };
  }

  const trainingDataset = tf.data.generator(() => dataGenerator("Training"))
    .shuffle(100)
    .batch(100);
  const validationDataset = tf.data.generator(() => dataGenerator("Validation"))
    .shuffle(100)
    .batch(100);

  // Fitting the model
  await model.fitDataset(trainingDataset, {
    epochs: 5,
    validationData: validationDataset
  });
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

nothing. message is info-only and comes from underlying tensorflow c library (where it was introduced at the wrong message level) used by tfjs-node.

planned upgrade of shared library from 2.7.3 to 2.9.1 will take care of that - it should be part of tfjs 3.21 once its released.